# How to select time field when querying in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know how to use query statement to return `time` field in Apache IoTDB(Internet of Things Database)?

I tried `select s_1,time from root.ln.** limit 5` command in IoTDB,
& the message reported `Fail to execute select s_1,time from root.ln.** limit 5` error.

While the fields & time series are already set in IoTDB. The time field is typically represented by a reserved keyword like `time` or `timestamp.`

**How can I check the time related to query results in IoTDB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless doing aggregation query, the time column of the query results in Apache IoTDB will be returned by default. For example, if you execute query statement like `select s_1 from root.ln.** limit 5`, then the result column will look like the following (which should already give you the time data you want) :

```
time | s_1
   1 | a
   2 | b
   3 | c
   4 | d
   5 | e
```